# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error using multiparty package in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image-uploading

I'm a newbie in Node.js and trying to upload an image from my html. I created the button which can upload image to my web app by using below html code.

```
<li><a onclick="getFile()" style="cursor:pointer; color:#000000;">Choose File</a></li>
<li><a onclick="uploadFile();" style="cursor: pointer; color:#000000;">Upload</a></li>
<li><a onclick="save2()" id="imageSave" style="cursor:pointer; color:#000000;">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="/location" style="color:#000000">Back to view</a></li>

<form action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div style='height:0px; width:0px; overflow:hidden;'><input type="file" name="upFile" id="upFile" onchange="getCmaFileView(this, 'name')" target="dropzone_1"/></div>
  <div style='height:0px; width:0px; overflow:hidden;'><input type="submit" name="Upload" id="Upload" /></div>
</form>
```

After clicking upload `li` it uploads an image from node.js by using multiparty package like code below.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {

        var form = new multiparty.Form();

      // get field name & value
      form.on('field',function(name,value){
           console.log('normal field / name = '+name+' , value = '+value);
      });

      // file upload handling
      form.on('part',function(part){
           var filename;
           var size;
           if (part.filename) {
                 filename = part.filename;
                 size = part.byteCount;
           }else{
                 part.resume();

           }

           console.log("Write Streaming file :"+global_username);
           var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/opt/work/files/'+global_username);
           writeStream.filename = filename;
           part.pipe(writeStream);

           part.on('data',function(chunk){
                 console.log(global_username+'.png'+' read '+chunk.length + 'bytes');
           });

           part.on('end',function(){
                 console.log(global_username+'.png'+' Part read complete');
                 writeStream.end();
           });
      });

      // all uploads are completed
         form.on('close',function(){
           res.status(200);
      });

      // track progress
      form.on('progress',function(byteRead,byteExpected){
           console.log(' Reading total  '+byteRead+'/'+byteExpected);
      });
      form.on('error',function(){
        console.log('error');
      });

      form.parse(req);
});
```

It saves an image and uploads well, but it shows me an ERROR after waiting a while with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` message.

I think it is because of response. it means that after header goes post, should give it back response but it doesn't.

And actually, I wrote code that it gives response back in above code of Node.js

```
form.on('close',function(){
               res.status(200);
          });
```

However, it still gives same error... I don't know why.

Does anybody have an idea? or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return response to client `res.status(200)` sets status to response then you need to call `res.send()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then should I write like `res.status(200)` and then res.send() on the next line?